# What to do when marked as a duplicate, but no answer in the "original" is given?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I am trying to get a good answer to a question without being disruptive.

I have posted my question back in May ([Why are bool values compared bitwise in C++ rather than by their meaning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30160423/why-are-bool-values-compared-bitwise-in-c-rather-than-by-their-meaning)). No answers were given, but the question was marked as a duplicate (of [Accessing inactive union member - undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373203/accessing-inactive-union-member-undefined)).

There is clearly no answer to my question in the "original", it only deals with a mistake that i have made, while trying to show what i was asking about. (It's a wonderful question and has very informative answers, it's just that it has little to do with mine.)

Now, as i see my options are:

1. Forget about using SO. Ask the question somewhere else.
2. Keep editing my question, explaining what the difference between it and the original is. But when i have tried to do that, i got comments of very annoyed people, that i shouldn't do that.
3. Ask the question again. But that will be silly, since now it is definitely a duplicate... a duplicate of a "wrongly marked duplicate". And i will rightfully just be downvoted to hell and then have the question closed.
4. Go to the "original" question, and offer a bounty to have my question answered. But the answer to my question will likely add little to the people who are searching for answers on union types. It is also unclear how i would post this bounty... by editing the original question and adding my requirements? I would be quite annoyed if somebody would basterdise my good question in this manner.
5. Some other way

I hope that the answer is #5. And that i am just too stupid to figure out what the respectful way to request to have the question answered. I would probably even do a bounty on my first question, but you can't bounty any question marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I have seen the strangest flaging on this site, I've been on this site (on an older account I abandoned) almost since it's inception. You can dispute it here on meta as you have done and hope that some all forgiving moderator decides to have mercy on you and undoes the flag. I've seen it happen many times, silly and irrelevant flags, and them being undone. This is the best first step. I find that if one person flags something others seem to just follow suit without always looking. And once a person makes a decision....well, good luck arguing. People hate being told they made a wrong decision.

Comment: #2 - deviantfan is wrong, you *should* edit the question to clarify, then it will be automatically run through the reopening review queue.

Comment: You should update your question with a solid reasoning why the dupe doesn't answer your question. Something like *My problem is in [code] but the undefined behavior as explained in [answer from dupe] doesn't cover this case because....*